# PHP to JQuery function String

Tags: php, jquery, special-characters

This is the data Im getting from my database to PHP:

```
 <p><em>ozantrkcn NABER</em> IYI PANPA SENDE NABER <strong>IYI YA NOOLSUN UGRASIYORUZ ISTE</strong></p>
```

This is how I get It in php.. I get it as $rec. $rec[0] has is ID, $rec[1] is title and $rec[2] is text I change < > these since they are special characters and JQuery would have problems with reading it... I had to put \" if I dont I get another error for the spaces in the text:

```
 $sql = "select * from duyurular";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    while ($rec = $db->getRowArray($result)) {


       $text = str_replace('>',"&gt;",$rec[2]);
       $text = str_replace('<',"&lt;",$rec[2]);
       $title = str_replace('<',"&lt;",$rec[1]);
       $title = str_replace('>',"&gt;",$rec[1]);


        echo "\n<tr class='datastr'>";
        echo "\n<td id='text$rec[0]' ondblclick='imageClick($rec[0]1)' onclick='getDetails(\"$text\", $rec[0], \"$title\")'>$rec[1]</td>
        <td class='functions'>
        <i id='btnEdit$rec[0]' class='fa fa-pencil icons' title='Değiştir' onclick='imageClick($rec[0]1)'></i>
        <i id='btnDEL$rec[0]' title='Sil' class='fa fa-trash icons' onclick='imageClick($rec[0]2)'></i>
        <input id='btnUpdate$rec[0]' style='visibility:hidden' type='button' value='Onayla' onclick='updateNews($rec[0])'>
        </td>";
        echo "\n</tr>";

    }
```

This is the function - JavaScript Code (JQuery) - where Im getting Error..
 According to what error says.. Function parameters are the problems:

```
    function getDetails(text,did,title){

        detailText = ""+text;


         detailText = detailText.replace("&gt;", '>');
         detailText = detailText.replace("&lt;", '<');
         title = title.replace("&gt;", '>');
         title = title.replace("&lt;", '<');


          $("#editor").css("visibility","visible");

         ineditor = "<textarea class='ckeditor' name='editor1' cols='30' rows='10'></textarea>";
         CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(detailText);
         $("#info").html(title);
         $("#btnUpdate").attr("onclick","updateNews("+did+")");

        alert("calisti");





}
```

This is the Error Im getting and there is an arrow pointing at to quoteation mark :

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal


getDetails("<p><em>ozantrkcn NABER</em> IYI PANPA SENDE NABER <strong>I
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're dumping text into a javascript context. e.g:

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello';
?>

<script>
   alert(<?php echo $foo ?>);
</script>
```

would produce the literal text/code

```
 alert(hello);
```

in the html/js your browser downloads. When the browser executes that code, it'll look for a variable named `hello`, which doesn't exist. Never dump text from PHP directly into JS code. Always use `json_encode()`, so that whatever you're dumping becomes syntactically valid JS strings:

```
 alert(<?php echo json_encode($foo) ?>);
```

becomes

```
 alert('hello');
```

which then pops up an alert box with the word `hello` in it, as expected.